# LINQ query to SQL query conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hi. I want to convert a LINQ query to a SQL Query. I am new to LINQ. Can someone help me with the conversion? Here is my Linq code:

```
 var val = from AppDetails in db.ApplicantProfile
                  join PRQDetails in db.PrqcreatedInformation on AppDetails.ApplicantProfileId equals PRQDetails.ApplicantId
                  where PRQDetails.ConsiderForPrq == true
                  orderby PRQDetails.Entrydate ascending
                  select new
                  {
                      Prefix = AppDetails.Prefix.Name,
                      FirstName = AppDetails.FirstName,
                      MiddleName = AppDetails.MiddleName,
                      LastName = AppDetails.LastName,
                      ArdisPersonId = AppDetails.ArdisPersonId,
                      ApplicantProfileId = AppDetails.ApplicantProfileId,
                      PRQEntryDate = PRQDetails.Entrydate,
                      PrqUpdated = PRQDetails.PrqUpdated,
                      IsSendtoARDs = PRQDetails.IsSendtoArds,
                      DataSentToARDis=PRQDetails.DataSentToArdis,
                      DataSentToARDisBy=PRQDetails.DataSentToArdisBy 
                  };
```

Comment: How does `Prefix` link to `AppDetails`?

Comment: Prefix is just a column alias. Its equable to SELECT [Name] as 'Prefix' FROM AppDetails

Comment: @HassanGulzar: Not the alias, its about AppDetails.Prefix

Comment: AppDetails is represent a single row of the table ApplicantProfile table.

Comment: You may also consider LinqPad (or simply debug sql server), you'll see the sql query LINQ uses in clear.

Comment: In fact, you are right. I see the AppDetails.Prefix.Name

Answer (score 4):

It will be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
   p.Name,
   ad.FirstName,
   ad.MiddleName,
   ad.LastName,
   ad.ArdisPersonId,
   ad.ApplicationProfileId,
   prq.Entrydate,
   prq.PrqUpdated,
   prq.IsSendtoArds,
   prq.DataSentToArdis,
   prq.DataSentToArdisBy 
FROM AppDetails ad
INNER JOIN PRQDetails prq 
   ON ad.ApplicantProfileId = prq.ApplicantId
INNER JOIN Prefix p
   ON ?????? = ?????
WHERE prq.ConsiderForPrq = 1
ORDER BY prq.Entrydate
```

But without info on how `AppDetails` links to `Prefix` its hard to fill in the `????`

Comment: AppDetails seems to have a relation to a table called Prefix since Prefix seems to be composed in AppDetails

Comment: @HassanGulzar - You've provided no further information. Its obvious that AppDetails links to Prefix, as is demonstrated by me adding an INNER JOIN to it, its not clear what the fields are which link the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386961(v=VS.90).aspx

Note that in their example, the variable db is the DatabaseContext.